# 2006 Pontiac torrent

Tags: starting, pontiac, torrent

2006 Pontiac torrent won't start. Brand new battery one week old, will not start with remote starter or either key! All the lights come on , radio and electronics but when I turn the key the final bit to start it .. Nothing happens ! Nothing at all no sound. This problem is on and off some days it's starting without issue and other days wont start ! Any ideas? And cost to repair? 
Anything helps!! Thanks!!!

Comment: This sounds more like a faulty starter relay or possibly an immobiliser problem than a bad battery connection.

Answer (score 1):

I would still check to voltage at the battery as I don't like to make assumptions, but I would check the terminal battery cables and clean them and the contact points on the battery.  I'm fairly confident that is the issue, based on the description.  If they are the universal clamp together type, unbolt those and clean that as well.  All the pieces have to be clean for the voltage to flow well.

I don't recommend this type of battery terminal end for that reason.  Here is a picture:
[image]

I also use the red/green treated rings on the battery connectors to reduce buildup of corrosion, which is well worth the little money for them.

If this is not the issue, I would look into the ignition key system on the column for an electrical issue there.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @James Drinkard to start by finding out if there is good enough contact between the battery and the rest of the car to support running the starter.

One thing in particular to check, I know there is no noise when you try to start it, but does the voltage sag? You can have someone try to start it while you test the voltage (touch the probe to the connectors on the battery cables, not the battery terminals). If the voltage sags then the ignition is working and the problem is probably a busted solenoid or a connection to the solenoid. Given that it starts just fine from time to time this sounds like a bad connection. If I had to place a bet, it's a bad connection between the ignition switch and the solenoid. Possibly a bad ground as well. Start with what James gave you, and then try the voltage sag test. It will help you slice and dice the problem to narrow down what is not right..

Hope that helps!